# Getting execution time of a process by another process in C

Tags: c, linux

I want to find the execution time of a process by second process in C (second process can suspend first process Whenever it's necessary.)My algorithm is running a function by the second process that returns PID of first process by name in a loop while. because if a process completed its name doesn't exist in process list and its PID must be equal to zero.

I found a function for this purpose, but the returned PID of the process by this function after termination of process is equal to the PID of the process while is running. 
Can someone help me solve this problem?
Thanks.

```
int mygetpid(char processname[100])
{
 char line[1000];
 char totstr[200];
 strcpy(totstr, "pidof ");
 strcat(totstr, processname);
 FILE *cmd = popen(totstr, "r");
 fgets(line, 1000, cmd);
 pid_t pid = strtoul(line, NULL, 10);
 pclose(cmd);
 return pid;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some context around the program which you are trying to time? For example, if you are able to invoke program 1 within program 2, then it would be pretty easy to time. Alternatively, could you wrap program 1 in a script that calls the program and times it? These strategies would be a more fool-proof and accurate way to time something, as your strategy is just polling the OS

Comment: Thanks for your reply.    would you please explain more? I know c# and doesn't know so much OS.

Comment: Let's call "Program 1" the program that you want to measure. What is the nature of Program 1? Are you starting it yourself on-demand, or is it out of your control about when it starts and ends?
If you have control over starting and stopping it, then you can wrap Program 1 inside of another program (a shell, C, C#, whatever) that will call Program 1 and time it. Something like (pseudocode):
    `start_timer();
    call(Program_1);
    end_timer();`

Comment: Thanks. Program_1 is a benchmark that I shouldn't stop it, only I can suspend it.